# Syntax Error On Google Chrome JavaScript console

Tags: javascript, syntax, error-handling

I am getting a Syntax error on my code where the input should be greater than 0 and less than 11 for a battleship game.

Here is the line of code if anyone has any suggestions it would be much appreciated.

```
document.getElementById("bullet").elements['bulletX'].value(>0 && <11);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
var element = document.getElementById("bullet").elements['bulletX'].value;

if(element > 0 && element < 11) {
    // do the job
}
```